# If $I$ is an invertible ideal, then $I=(I^{-1})^{-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $I$ be an [invertible (fractional) ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal) in $R$. Show that $I=(I^{-1})^{-1}$.

Does it suffice to just refer to the inverse of the fractional ideal $I$, i.e. $II^{-1} = R$? Is it really that easy or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean fractional ideals instead of ideals?

Comment: Yes, sorry I will make an edit.

Comment: You need to check how you have been defined $I^{-1}$. Perhaps they defined it as $I^{-1}=\{x\in K:\ xI\subset R\}$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Then you would need to show that nesting that definition gives you back $I$.

Comment: plop is correct, but you must remember that you will need to use the assumption that the ideal is invertible. Namely, the equality $II^{-1} = R$ can be taken as the definition of an ideal being invertible, since if there exists some $J$ for which $IJ = R$, one can show that $J = I^{-1}$ as defined by plop. Nesting the definitions does not formally give an equality of $I$ and $(I^{-1})^{-1}$ using only that $I$ is an ideal. In fact, that claim I made above seems to me a better approach to proving what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I\subseteq(I^{-1})^{-1}$ always holds: since $II^{-1}\subseteq R$, $x\in I$ implies $xI^{-1}\subseteq R$, hence $x\in (I^{-1})^{-1}$.
For the converse we use that $I$ is invertible, that is, $II^{-1}=R$. In particular, we may write $1=\sum a_ix_i$ with $a_i\in I$ and $x_i\in I^{-1}$. Now, if $x\in (I^{-1})^{-1}$ we have $xI^{-1}\subseteq R$. But then $x=\sum a_i(xx_i)\in I$.